# How to change the value of CustomFields in Test-Case TFS API 2013?

Tags: c#, .net, tfs

I'm trying to make a utility for working with TFS and I get some values from testcases:

```
entrie.TestCase.CustomFields["IsReference"].Value, 
entrie.TestCase.CustomFields["Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.AutomationStatus"].Value,
entrie.TestCase.CustomFields["TestType"].Value  
///...
```

i show this values to the user, and after that i want to change this values. I tried:

```
testCase.CustomFields["Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.AutomationStatus"] = item.Value; // Error: The indexer has no setter
testCase.Priority = item.Value; // OK
```

How to change `CustomFields` in test-case with tfs api?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`CustomFields`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.testmanagement.client.itestbase.customfields.aspx) is a [`FieldCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.workitemtracking.client.fieldcollection(v=vs.120).aspx) who's indexer [has no setter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb164286(v=vs.120).aspx), however the indexer return a [`Field`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.workitemtracking.client.field(v=vs.120).aspx) who's property [`Value`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.workitemtracking.client.field.value(v=vs.120).aspx) has one

Just change:

```
testCase.CustomFields["Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.AutomationStatus"] = item.Value;
```

to:

```
testCase.CustomFields["Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.AutomationStatus"].Value = item.Value;
```